# Finding a Point Closest to the Point Where Edges Meet on the Base of a Square Pyramid

Tags: geometry

The question is as follows:

> Pyramid TABCD has a 20-cm square base ABCD. The edges that meet at T are 27 cm long. Make a diagram of TABCD, showing F, the point of ABCD closest to T. To the nearest 0.1 cm, find the height TF. Find the volume of TABCD, to the nearest cc.

*I am assuming that `cc` means `cubic centimeters`*.

I do not know how to find point F since it needs to be closest to T. I initially thought of it as the slant height, but I am doubting myself. Is there an efficient method for doing this problem?

Comment: $F$ is simply the foot of the altitude from $T$. Since the edges are all the same length, it should be fairly easy to figure out what this point must be from symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

Since the base is square and the edges that meet at T are equal, this is a completely symmetric situation.  You should find it easy to see that F is the middle point of the base.  The sides of that base are 37 cm so, using the Pythagorean theorem, the diagonals of the base are $\sqrt{2(37)^2}= 37\sqrt{2}$.  The distance from one corner of the base to F is half that, $(37/2)\sqrt{2}$.  You can think of that as one leg of a right triangle where the other leg is the line from F to T and the hypotenuse is the 27 cm line.  Again using the Pythagorean theorem, that height, h, is given by $h^2+ (37/2)^2= 27^2$ or $h= \sqrt{729- 342.25}= \sqrt{386.75}$.

The formula for the volume of such a pyramid is $\frac{s^2h}{3}$ where s is the 37 cm side of the base and h is the height just calculated.

Comment: How did you find the diagonals of the base to be $37\sqrt{2}$? I thought that it was $20\sqrt{2}$.